# error: '_mm512_loadu_epi64' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, intrinsics, avx512

I'm trying to create a minimal reproducer for [this issue report](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/753). There seems to be some problems with AVX-512, which is shipping on the latest Apple machines with Skylake processors.

According to [GCC6 release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html) the AVX-512 gear should be available. According to the [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=vmovdqu64) `vmovdqu64` is available with `AVX-512VL` and `AVX-512F`:

```
$ cat test.cxx
#include <cstdint>
#include <immintrin.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    uint64_t x[8];
    __m512i y = _mm512_loadu_epi64(x);
    return 0;
}
```

And then:

```
$ /opt/local/bin/g++-mp-6 -mavx512f -Wa,-q test.cxx -o test.exe
test.cxx: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
test.cxx:6:37: error: '_mm512_loadu_epi64' was not declared in this scope
     __m512i y = _mm512_loadu_epi64(x);
                                     ^
$ /opt/local/bin/g++-mp-6 -mavx -mavx2 -mavx512f -Wa,-q test.cxx -o test.exe
test.cxx: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
test.cxx:6:37: error: '_mm512_loadu_epi64' was not declared in this scope
     __m512i y = _mm512_loadu_epi64(x);
                                     ^
$ /opt/local/bin/g++-mp-6 -msse4.1 -msse4.2 -mavx -mavx2 -mavx512f -Wa,-q test.cxx -o test.exe
test.cxx: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
test.cxx:6:37: error: '_mm512_loadu_epi64' was not declared in this scope
     __m512i y = _mm512_loadu_epi64(x);
                                     ^
```

I walked the options back to `-msse2` without success. I seem to be missing something.

What is required to engage AVX-512 for modern GCC?

---

According to a `/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-6 -v`, these are the header search paths:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /opt/local/include/gcc6/c++/
 /opt/local/include/gcc6/c++//x86_64-apple-darwin13
 /opt/local/include/gcc6/c++//backward
 /opt/local/lib/gcc6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/6.5.0/include
 /opt/local/include
 /opt/local/lib/gcc6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/6.5.0/include-fixed
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks
 /Library/Frameworks
```

And then:

```
$ grep -R '_mm512_' /opt/local/lib/gcc6/ | grep avx512f | head -n 8
/opt/local/lib/gcc6//gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/6.5.0/include/avx512fintrin.h:_mm512_set_epi64 (long long __A, long long __B, long long __C,
/opt/local/lib/gcc6//gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/6.5.0/include/avx512fintrin.h:_mm512_set_epi32 (int __A, int __B, int __C, int __D,
/opt/local/lib/gcc6//gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/6.5.0/include/avx512fintrin.h:_mm512_set_pd (double __A, double __B, double __C, double __D,
/opt/local/lib/gcc6//gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/6.5.0/include/avx512fintrin.h:_mm512_set_ps (float __A, float __B, float __C, float __D,
/opt/local/lib/gcc6//gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/6.5.0/include/avx512fintrin.h:#define _mm512_setr_epi64(e0,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7)                       \
/opt/local/lib/gcc6//gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/6.5.0/include/avx512fintrin.h:  _mm512_set_epi64(e7,e6,e5,e4,e3,e2,e1,e0)
/opt/local/lib/gcc6//gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/6.5.0/include/avx512fintrin.h:#define _mm512_setr_epi32(e0,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,                       \
/opt/local/lib/gcc6//gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/6.5.0/include/avx512fintrin.h:  _mm512_set_epi32(e15,e14,e13,e12,e11,e10,e9,e8,e7,e6,e5,e4,e3,e2,e1,e0)
...
```

Comment: Works on [clang with `-mavx512f`](https://godbolt.org/z/hTKWcI). Try to search through the headers for the related intrinsics and see if you can find the function. If you can't find it you either need a newer version of gcc or chances are it just hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: With no masking, there's no reason for this intrinsic to exist or to ever use it.  It's just confusing vs. `_mm512_loadu_si512`.  Intel's guide does specify that it exists (https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,AVX_512,SVML,Other&expand=2403,4147&text=_mm512_loadu_), but maybe gcc doesn't define it.  SSE* and AVX1/2 options are irrelevent to whether or not GCC headers define this intrinsic in terms of gcc built-ins or not; `-mavx512f` already implies all of the Intel SSE/AVX extensions before AVX512.

Comment: @user2176127 Not present on gcc trunk on Godbolt, and in clang it's only present in trunk, not 7.0.  The aligned version is present in both, though: `_mm512_load_epi64`.  And they They both have the `maskz` version.  Pretty weird, but like I said super easy to avoid by just using the si512 version.

Comment: Yeah, grepping the GCC include directories are not returning hits for `$ grep -R '_mm512_' /opt/local/lib/gcc6/ | grep _mm512_loadu_epi64`.

Comment: @Peter - I think `_mm512_load_epi64` is close enough. I can get the assembler error message using it. (I am trying to reproduce the integrated assembler error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With no masking, there's no reason for this intrinsic to exist or to ever use it instead of the equivalent `_mm512_loadu_si512`**.   It's just confusing, and could trick human readers into thinking it was a `vmovq` zero-extending load of a single `epi64`.

[Intel's intrinsics finder does specify that it exists](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,AVX_512,SVML,Other&expand=2403,4147&text=_mm512_loadu_), but even current trunk gcc (on Godbolt) doesn't define it.

Almost all AVX512 instructions support merge-masking and zero-masking.  Instructions that used to be purely bitwise / whole-register with no meaningful element boundaries now come in 32 and 64-bit element flavours, like `vpxord` and `vpxorq`.  Or [`vmovdqa32` and `vmovdqa64`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movdqa:vmovdqa32:vmovdqa64).  But **using either version with no masking is still just a normal vector load / store / register-copy, and it's not meaningful to specify anything about element-size for them in the C++ source with intrinsics, only the total vector width.**

See also [What is the difference between _mm512_load_epi32 and _mm512_load_si512?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53905757/what-is-the-difference-between-mm512-load-epi32-and-mm512-load-si512)

---

SSE* and AVX1/2 options are irrelevent to whether or not GCC headers define this intrinsic in terms of gcc built-ins or not; `-mavx512f` already implies all of the Intel SSE/AVX extensions before AVX512.

---

It is present in clang trunk (but not 7.0 so it was only very recently added).

- unaligned `_mm512_loadu_si512` - supported everywhere, use this
- unaligned `_mm512_loadu_epi64` - clang trunk, not gcc.
- aligned `_mm512_load_si512`  - supported everywhere, use this
- aligned `_mm512_load_epi64`  - also supported everywhere, surprisingly.
- unaligned `_mm512_maskz_loadu_epi64`  - supported everywhere, use this for zero-masked loads
- unaligned `_mm512_mask_loadu_epi64` - supported everywhere, use this for merge-mask loads.

This code compiles on gcc as early as 4.9.0, and mainline (Linux) clang as early as 3.9, both with `-march=avx512f`.  Or if they support it, `-march=skylake-avx512` or `-march=knl`.  I haven't tested with Apple Clang.

```
#include <immintrin.h>

__m512i loadu_si512(void *x) { return _mm512_loadu_si512(x); }
__m512i load_epi64(void *x)  {  return _mm512_load_epi64(x); }
//__m512i loadu_epi64(void *x) {  return _mm512_loadu_epi64(x); }

__m512i loadu_maskz(void *x) { return _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi64(0xf0, x); }
__m512i loadu_mask(void *x)  { return _mm512_mask_loadu_epi64(_mm512_setzero_si512(), 0xf0, x); }
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%0A__m512i+loadu_si512(void+*x)+%7B+return+_mm512_loadu_si512(x)%3B+%7D%0A__m512i+load_epi64(void+*x)++%7B++return+_mm512_load_epi64(x)%3B+%7D%0A//__m512i+loadu_epi64(void+*x)+%7B++return+_mm512_loadu_epi64(x)%3B+%7D%0A%0A__m512i+loadu_maskz(void+*x)+%7B+return+_mm512_maskz_loadu_epi64(0xf0,+x)%3B+%7D%0A__m512i+loadu_mask(void+*x)++%7B+return+_mm512_mask_loadu_epi64(_mm512_setzero_si512(),+0xf0,+x)%3B+%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:51.80156657963446,l:'4',m:32.73092369477912,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang390,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'1',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-march%3Dskylake+-mavx512f+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+3.9.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:46.354326123627544,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+clang+3.9.0',t:'0')),l:'4',m:20.914750181593334,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:51.80156657963446,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g490,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'1',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-mavx512f+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+4.9.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:56.03983023179889,l:'4',m:58.266666666666666,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+4.9.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:41.733333333333334,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:48.19843342036554,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4); you can uncomment the `_mm512_loadu_epi64` and flip the compiler to clang trunk to see it work there.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance... When you say *"with no masking"*, what do you mean?

Comment: Without an AVX512 mask argument.  The whole point of having different element-size versions of vector loads is for use with a mask register, like `_mm512_maskz_loadu_epi64(0x55, x);` that zeros the odd elements for free while loading.  Like `vmovdqu64       (%rdi), %zmm0{%k1}{z}`.  When elements are loaded into the destination unchanged, element boundaries are meaningless.  That's why AVX2 and earlier don't have them for bitwise booleans (like `_mm_xor_si128`) and loads/stores like `_mm_load_si128`).

Comment: And it's why asm instructions like `vmovdqu64/32/16/8` exist.  http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVDQU:VMOVDQU8:VMOVDQU16:VMOVDQU32:VMOVDQU64.html  Notice the `{%k1}{z}` decoration in the above AT&T syntax asm instruction.  That means to assemble with the EVEX prefix encoding mask-register = k1, and zero-masking (not merge-masking).  For most instructions, the no-masking encoding is what would have meant `k0`, so there's an extra mask register you can use as a destination for compare-into-mask or `kshift` / `kunpack` / `ktest` / `kortest` / etc. instructions.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware a mask was needed to load a register with a value from memory under AVX-512.

Comment: @jww: it isn't needed.  (just finished editing my last comment to mention that the encoding that would mean `k0` actually means "no mask" in those contexts).  So you could say that there's always masking in machine code, but there's an architectural zero-register that you use for no-masking.  But in asm text syntax, and C++ intrinsics, you can use the no-masking version of an instruction or intrinsic.  If you aren't using a mask in the intrinsic that's purely bitwise, there's no need to care about different element-size versions of it.  In asm you just need to pick one, in C++ the compiler can

Comment: Here's the other piece of the puzzle... When using the Clang integrated assembler, [Clang 7.0 is required](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39875#c4) due to a LLVM issue that was fixed in February, 2018. Also see LLVM Issue 39875, [Error: instruction requires: AVX-512 ISA when using -mavx512](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39875).

Comment: @jww: You had a similar link in the question.  Seems unrelated to choice of intrinsic; if that didn't assemble then presumably no AVX512F instructions would, because of some front-end bug leading to the assembler deciding not to accept AVX512F instructions.  So you can change the test-case to use a portable intrinsic.

Answer (score 0):

_mm512_loadu_epi64 is not available in 32-bit mode. You need to compile for 64-bit mode. In general, AVX512 works best in 64-bit mode.

Comment: Which compiler is that true for?  That sounds like a bug because `vmovdqu64` is available in either mode.  (Agreed on using 64-bit mode so you have 32 instead of 8 registers, though!  And so integer registers can hold a 64-element mask for AVX512BW.)