# Am I missing a target-feature for AVX512 when I compile my Rust code?

Tags: rust, simd, rust-cargo, avx2, avx512

I have written some Rust functions that use AVX2 and AVX512 instructions to speed up image compositing. I am using an AMD 7950x CPU.

When I run `RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=native" cargo bench` I get:

```
test overlay_using_avx2   ... bench:     483,596 ns/iter (+/- 10,006)
test overlay_using_avx512 ... bench:     317,818 ns/iter (+/- 729)
```

However, I would like to build the executable on one machine and the run it on another machine. Therefore, I am explicitly enabling the features that my code needs and checking at runtime if they are present. However, when I do this, the AVX512 benchmark runs slower and I don't understand why. I am running:

`RUSTFLAGS="-C target-feature=+avx2,+avx,+sse2,+avx512f,+avx512bw" cargo bench`:

```
test overlay_using_avx2   ... bench:     490,664 ns/iter (+/- 13,172)
test overlay_using_avx512 ... bench:   1,519,720 ns/iter (+/- 38,608)
```

Do I need to enable some other feature(s) from the `rustc --print target-features` list? Is it possible to see which features were enabled by setting `target-cpu=native` ?

My benchmark code is below and runs on nightly:

```rust
#![feature(stdsimd)]
#![feature(test)]

use std::arch::x86_64::*;

unsafe fn overlay_chunk_avx2(this_chunk: &mut [u8], image_chunk: &[u8], c1: __m256i, c2: __m256i) {
    let this_ptr = this_chunk.as_mut_ptr() as *mut __m128i;
    let image_ptr = image_chunk.as_ptr() as *const __m128i;

    let this_argb = _mm_loadu_si128(this_ptr);
    let image_argb = _mm_loadu_si128(image_ptr);

    let this_u16 = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi16(this_argb);
    let image_u16 = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi16(image_argb);

    let image_alpha = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(image_u16, c1);
    let image_inv_alpha = _mm256_sub_epi8(c2, image_alpha);

    let this_blended = _mm256_mullo_epi16(this_u16, image_inv_alpha);
    let image_blended = _mm256_mullo_epi16(image_u16, image_alpha);

    let blended = _mm256_add_epi16(this_blended, image_blended);
    let divided = _mm256_srli_epi16(blended, 8);

    let lo_lane = _mm256_castsi256_si128(divided);
    let hi_lane = _mm256_extracti128_si256(divided, 1);

    let divided_u8 = _mm_packus_epi16(lo_lane, hi_lane);

    _mm_storeu_si128(this_ptr, divided_u8);
}

unsafe fn overlay_chunk_avx512(this_chunk: &mut [u8], image_chunk: &[u8], c1: __m512i, c2: __m512i) {
    let this_ptr = this_chunk.as_mut_ptr() as *mut i8;
    let image_ptr = image_chunk.as_ptr() as *const i8;

    let this_argb = _mm256_loadu_epi8(this_ptr);
    let image_argb = _mm256_loadu_epi8(image_ptr);

    let this_u16 = _mm512_cvtepu8_epi16(this_argb);
    let image_u16 = _mm512_cvtepu8_epi16(image_argb);

    let image_alpha = _mm512_shuffle_epi8(image_u16, c1);
    let image_inv_alpha = _mm512_sub_epi8(c2, image_alpha);

    let this_blended = _mm512_mullo_epi16(this_u16, image_inv_alpha);
    let image_blended = _mm512_mullo_epi16(image_u16, image_alpha);

    let blended = _mm512_add_epi16(this_blended, image_blended);

    let divided = _mm512_srli_epi16(blended, 8);
    let divided_u8 = _mm512_cvtepi16_epi8(divided);

    _mm256_storeu_epi8(this_ptr, divided_u8);
}

extern crate test;

#[bench]
fn overlay_using_avx2(bencher: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let mut frame = vec![0; 1920 * 1080 * 4];
    let image = vec![0; 1920 * 1080 * 4];

    let constant1 = unsafe { _mm256_set_epi8(-1, 24, -1, 24, -1, 24, -1, -1, -1, 16, -1, 16, -1, 16, -1, -1, -1, 8, -1, 8,  -1, 8, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1) };
    let constant2 = unsafe { _mm256_set_epi8(0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0) };

    bencher.iter(|| {
        let frame_chunks = frame.chunks_exact_mut(128 / 8);
        let image_chunks = image.chunks_exact(128 / 8);

        for (frame_chunk, image_chunk) in frame_chunks.zip(image_chunks) {
            unsafe { overlay_chunk_avx2(frame_chunk, image_chunk, constant1, constant2); }
        }
    });
}

#[bench]
fn overlay_using_avx512(bencher: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let mut frame = vec![0; 1920 * 1080 * 4];
    let image = vec![0; 1920 * 1080 * 4];

    let constant1 = unsafe { _mm512_set_epi8(-1, 56, -1, 56, -1, 56, -1, -1, -1, 48, -1, 48, -1, 48, -1, -1, -1, 40, -1, 40, -1, 40, -1, -1, -1, 32, -1, 32, -1, 32, -1, -1, -1, 24, -1, 24, -1, 24, -1, -1, -1, 16, -1, 16, -1, 16, -1, -1, -1, 8, -1, 8, -1, 8, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0,  -1, -1) };
    let constant2 = unsafe { _mm512_set_epi8(0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0) };

    bencher.iter(|| {
        let frame_chunks = frame.chunks_exact_mut(256 / 8);
        let image_chunks = image.chunks_exact(256 / 8);

        for (frame_chunk, image_chunk) in frame_chunks.zip(image_chunks) {
            unsafe { overlay_chunk_avx512(frame_chunk, image_chunk, constant1, constant2); }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you needed `+avx512vl` to properly handle `_mm256_loadu_epi8` and `_mm256_storeu_epi8`.

Without that feature: (https://godbolt.org/z/roo8vf38q)

```
example::overlay_chunk_avx512:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        push    r15
        push    r14
        push    r12
        push    rbx
        and     rsp, -64
        sub     rsp, 192
        mov     rbx, r9
        mov     r14, r8
        mov     r15, rdx
        mov     r12, rdi
        mov     rdi, rsp
        mov     rsi, r12
        call    core::core_arch::x86::avx512bw::_mm256_loadu_epi8
        vpmovzxbw       zmm0, ymmword ptr [rsp]
        vmovdqa64       zmmword ptr [rsp + 64], zmm0
        mov     rdi, rsp
        mov     rsi, r15
        vzeroupper
        call    core::core_arch::x86::avx512bw::_mm256_loadu_epi8
        vpmovzxbw       zmm0, ymmword ptr [rsp]
        vpshufb zmm1, zmm0, zmmword ptr [r14]
        vmovdqa64       zmm2, zmmword ptr [rbx]
        vpsubb  zmm2, zmm2, zmm1
        vpmullw zmm2, zmm2, zmmword ptr [rsp + 64]
        vpmullw zmm0, zmm1, zmm0
        vpaddw  zmm0, zmm2, zmm0
        vpsrlw  zmm0, zmm0, 8
        vpmovwb ymmword ptr [rsp + 32], zmm0
        lea     rsi, [rsp + 32]
        mov     rdi, r12
        vzeroupper
        call    core::core_arch::x86::avx512bw::_mm256_storeu_epi8
        lea     rsp, [rbp - 32]
        pop     rbx
        pop     r12
        pop     r14
        pop     r15
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

With that feature: (https://godbolt.org/z/oTvEaPhPb)

```
example::overlay_chunk_avx512:
        vpmovzxbw       zmm0, ymmword ptr [rdi]
        vpmovzxbw       zmm1, ymmword ptr [rdx]
        vpshufb zmm2, zmm1, zmmword ptr [r8]
        vmovdqa64       zmm3, zmmword ptr [r9]
        vpsubb  zmm3, zmm3, zmm2
        vpmullw zmm0, zmm3, zmm0
        vpmullw zmm1, zmm2, zmm1
        vpaddw  zmm0, zmm0, zmm1
        vpsrlw  zmm0, zmm0, 8
        vpmovwb ymmword ptr [rdi], zmm0
        vzeroupper
        ret
```

Comment: The resulting `vpmovzxbw` directly from memory and the `vpmovwb` to memory don't actually end up requiring `AVX512VL` but whatever

Comment: That's weird that it lets you use intrinsics from extensions that aren't enabled.  https://godbolt.org/z/d6h9e7feW shows that using AVX2 load/store intrinsics results in the good code-gen even without AVX-512VL enabled. (Like `_mm256_loadu_si256(this_ptr as *const __m256i);` which unfortunately requires the case to `*__m256i` just like in C; too bad Rust didn't use `void*` from the start like with newer C intrinsics). With Xeon Phi discontinued, AVX-512 without AVX-512VL is lower priority for compiler devs to worry about, but allowing intrinsics and then butchering them seems bad.

Comment: (I've never liked un-masked `_mm_loadu_epi8` or the `_mm256` version.  It's just a full-vector load; we don't need a new intrinsic for it.  The generic pointer arg type is nice, but not at the expense of a weird name that looks like a single-element load, and that's not portable to all compilers.  [How to emulate \_mm256\_loadu\_epi32 with gcc or clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59649287) .  And [\_mm256\_loadu\_epi64, \_mm256\_storeu\_epi64 require avx512vl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66687838) reports that unlike rustc, clang rejects those intrinsics without AVX-512VL