# Slow SIMD performance - no inlining

Tags: rust, simd, sse, avx2

Consider following examples for calculating sum of i32 array:

Example1: Simple for loop

```
pub fn vec_sum_for_loop_i32(src: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let mut sum = 0;
    for c in src {
        sum += *c;
    }

    sum
}
```

Example2: Explicit SIMD sum:

```
use std::arch::x86_64::*;
// #[inline]
pub fn vec_sum_simd_direct_loop(src: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    #[cfg(debug_assertions)]
    assert!(src.as_ptr() as u64 % 64 == 0);
    #[cfg(debug_assertions)]
    assert!(src.len() % (std::mem::size_of::<__m256i>() / std::mem::size_of::<i32>()) == 0);

    let p_src = src.as_ptr();
    let batch_size = std::mem::size_of::<__m256i>() / std::mem::size_of::<i32>();

    #[cfg(debug_assertions)]
    assert!(src.len() % batch_size == 0);

    let result: i32;
    unsafe {
        let mut offset: isize = 0;
        let total: isize = src.len() as isize;
        let mut curr_sum = _mm256_setzero_si256();

        while offset < total {
            let curr = _mm256_load_epi32(p_src.offset(offset));
            curr_sum = _mm256_add_epi32(curr_sum, curr);
            offset += 8;
        }

        // this can be reduced with hadd.
        let a0 = _mm256_extract_epi32::<0>(curr_sum);
        let a1 = _mm256_extract_epi32::<1>(curr_sum);
        let a2 = _mm256_extract_epi32::<2>(curr_sum);
        let a3 = _mm256_extract_epi32::<3>(curr_sum);
        let a4 = _mm256_extract_epi32::<4>(curr_sum);
        let a5 = _mm256_extract_epi32::<5>(curr_sum);
        let a6 = _mm256_extract_epi32::<6>(curr_sum);
        let a7 = _mm256_extract_epi32::<7>(curr_sum);

        result = a0 + a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7;
    }

    result
}
```

When I tried to benchmark the code the first example got ~23GB/s (which is close to theoretical maximum for my RAM speed). Second example got 8GB/s.

When looking at the assembly with cargo asm first example translates into unrolled SIMD optimized loops:

```
.LBB11_7:
 sum += *c;
 movdqu  xmm2, xmmword, ptr, [rcx, +, 4*rax]
 paddd   xmm2, xmm0
 movdqu  xmm0, xmmword, ptr, [rcx, +, 4*rax, +, 16]
 paddd   xmm0, xmm1
 movdqu  xmm1, xmmword, ptr, [rcx, +, 4*rax, +, 32]
 movdqu  xmm3, xmmword, ptr, [rcx, +, 4*rax, +, 48]
 movdqu  xmm4, xmmword, ptr, [rcx, +, 4*rax, +, 64]
 paddd   xmm4, xmm1
 paddd   xmm4, xmm2
 movdqu  xmm2, xmmword, ptr, [rcx, +, 4*rax, +, 80]
 paddd   xmm2, xmm3
 paddd   xmm2, xmm0
 movdqu  xmm0, xmmword, ptr, [rcx, +, 4*rax, +, 96]
 paddd   xmm0, xmm4
 movdqu  xmm1, xmmword, ptr, [rcx, +, 4*rax, +, 112]
 paddd   xmm1, xmm2
 add     rax, 32
 add     r11, -4
 jne     .LBB11_7
.LBB11_8:
 test    r10, r10
 je      .LBB11_11
 lea     r11, [rcx, +, 4*rax]
 add     r11, 16
 shl     r10, 5
 xor     eax, eax
```

Second example doesn't have any loop unrolling and doesn't even inline code to _mm256_add_epi32:

```
...
movaps  xmmword, ptr, [rbp, +, 320], xmm7
 movaps  xmmword, ptr, [rbp, +, 304], xmm6
 and     rsp, -32
 mov     r12, rdx
 mov     rdi, rcx
 lea     rcx, [rsp, +, 32]
 let mut curr_sum = _mm256_setzero_si256();
 call    core::core_arch::x86::avx::_mm256_setzero_si256
 movaps  xmm6, xmmword, ptr, [rsp, +, 32]
 movaps  xmm7, xmmword, ptr, [rsp, +, 48]
 while offset < total {
 test    r12, r12
 jle     .LBB13_3
 xor     esi, esi
 lea     rbx, [rsp, +, 384]
 lea     r14, [rsp, +, 64]
 lea     r15, [rsp, +, 96]
.LBB13_2:
 let curr = _mm256_load_epi32(p_src.offset(offset));
 mov     rcx, rbx
 mov     rdx, rdi
 call    core::core_arch::x86::avx512f::_mm256_load_epi32
 curr_sum = _mm256_add_epi32(curr_sum, curr);
 movaps  xmmword, ptr, [rsp, +, 112], xmm7
 movaps  xmmword, ptr, [rsp, +, 96], xmm6
 mov     rcx, r14
 mov     rdx, r15
 mov     r8, rbx
 call    core::core_arch::x86::avx2::_mm256_add_epi32
 movaps  xmm6, xmmword, ptr, [rsp, +, 64]
 movaps  xmm7, xmmword, ptr, [rsp, +, 80]
 offset += 8;
 add     rsi, 8
 while offset < total {
 add     rdi, 32
 cmp     rsi, r12
...
```

This of course is pretty trivial example and I don't plan to use hand crafted SIMD for simple sum. But it still puzzles me on why explicit SIMD is so slow and why using SIMD intrinsics led to such unoptimized code.

Comment: side-note: `// this can be reduced with hadd.` - yes if you're optimizing for code-size in bytes or instruction-count, not speed.  Otherwise see [Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35270026).  If you want simple source-code, store to a tmp array and loop over it.

Comment: You compiled with optimization enabled, and the equivalent of gcc/clang `-march=haswell` or `-mavx2`?  (Or `-mavx512vl` for `_mm256_load_epi32`)?  If not, that might be what defeats inlining.  I tried on https://godbolt.org/z/ffrr5P87z after figuring out that your [mcve] is missing `#![feature(stdsimd)]` at the top, and yeah it compiles poorly, but that's with no arch options.  The asm is only using SSE2 instructions even around calls to AVX2 functions, not `vmovaps`.

Comment: Sorry about missing feature(stdsimd) in the repo.
I compiled the code with rustflags = "-C target-cpu=native" in config.toml.

I also tried explicit avx2 through RUSTFLAGS="-C target-feature=+avx2" cargo bench `

Comment: This has nothing to do with stdsimd. You need to do reporter static or dynamic cpu feature detection. -C target-cpu=native should work just fine for enabling avx2 everywhere. See: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/arch/index.html#cpu-feature-detection

Comment: N.B. On most architectures `[v]paddd` has a latency of 1 cycle but a troughput of 1/3 or 1/2, so you should use at least two separate accumulators, unless you are RAM-limited anyways or have other operations which happen in parallel. (Your problem apparently is more that the SIMD-calls don't get inlined, of course)

Comment: @chtz: memory-source `vpaddd` only has 2/clock throughput, limited by load-port throughput (https://uops.info/).  Except 3/clock on Alder Lake, hadn't realized they added another load port! But yes, 2 or 3 would help for data that's hot in L1d cache.  Or more so you're not right up against a latency and front-end throughput bottleneck.  LLVM typically unrolls tiny loops like this by 4 when auto-vectorizing, which is a good choice.  But OTOH, for small data that fits in L1d, your loop won't run a *huge* number of iterations, so startup overhead becomes a concern, unless it's always about 16kiB

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**It appears you forgot to tell rustc it was allowed to use AVX2 instructions everywhere, so it couldn't inline those functions.**  Instead, you get a total disaster where only the wrapper functions are compiled as AVX2-using functions, or something like that.

Works fine for me with `-O -C target-cpu=skylake-avx512` (https://godbolt.org/z/csY5or43T) so it can inline even the AVX512VL load you used, `_mm256_load_epi32`<sup>1</sup>, and then optimize it into a memory source operand for `vpaddd  ymm0, ymm0, ymmword ptr [rdi + 4*rax]` (AVX2) inside a tight loop.

In GCC / clang, you get an error like "inlining failed in call to always_inline `foobar`" in this case, instead of working but slow asm.  (See [this for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747789/the-effect-of-architecture-when-using-sse-avx-intrinisics)).  This is something Rust should probably sort out before this is ready for prime time, either be like MSVC and actually inline the instruction into a function using the intrinsic, or refuse to compile like GCC/clang.

**Footnote 1:**
See [How to emulate _mm256_loadu_epi32 with gcc or clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59649287/how-to-emulate-mm256-loadu-epi32-with-gcc-or-clang) if you didn't mean to use AVX512.

With `-O -C target-cpu=skylake` (just AVX2), it inlines everything else, including `vpaddd ymm`, but still calls out to a function that copies 32 bytes from memory to memory with AVX `vmovaps`.  It requires AVX512VL to inline the intrinsic, but later in the optimization process it realizes that with no masking, it's just a 256-bit load it should do without a bloated AVX-512 instruction.  It's kinda dumb that Intel even provided a no-masking version of `_mm256_mask[z]_loadu_epi32` that requires AVX-512.  Or dumb that gcc/clang/rustc consider it an AVX512 intrinsic.

Comment: Ups, yeah I didn't see that the instruction requires AVX512F. The CPU I used for testing has only AVX2. The comment from the linked thread was helpful - `Just use _mm256_loadu_si256 like a normal person. ` :). Removing the _mm256_load_epi32 solved the issue.

Comment: You can turn it per-function with `#[target_feature(enable = "avx2")]` (unfortunately it doesn't support AVX-512 yet). https://rust.godbolt.org/z/TTfa3fErx