# Why duplicated function in AVX512 to set zero?

Tags: simd, intrinsics, avx512

I came to those two functions:

- `_mm512_setzero_epi32()`
- `_mm512_setzero_si512()`

Logically, they are the same doing the same thing. Then I checked [the generated Assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/Kq4eYhWq5) and also found the same under different optimization levels.

It is a simple question to ask: why the AVX512 has such a duplicated design to set 0 for int?

Comment: There are some duplications in AVX-512: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53905757/what-is-the-difference-between-mm512-load-epi32-and-mm512-load-si512

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `_mm512_setzero_epi32()` is 100% redundant, no reason to ever use

For coding-style reasons, I'd recommend against it.  It doesn't follow the same pattern of `_mm_setzero_si128()` / `_mm256_setzero_si256()` for returning a SIMD-integer vector of all-zeros which `_mm512_setzero_si512()` follows.

The situation is very similar to the [useless and redundant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53604986/error-mm512-loadu-epi64-was-not-declared-in-this-scope) `_mm512_loadu_epi32` (which confusingly loads a whole 64-byte vector, not a 4-byte scalar).  **Not all compilers even support `_mm512_loadu_epi32` or `_mm512_loadu_epi64`, which might also be the case for `_mm512_setzero_epi32`; another reason to avoid it in favour of more standard and obvious ones.**

For redundant intrinsics like `_mm512_loadu_epi32` and `_mm512_and_epi32`, they're part of a pattern like `_mm512_maskz_loadu_epi32` and `_mm512_mask_loadu_epi32`; masking requires an element size, and having an unmasked intrinsic as least forms a pattern like for `_mm512_add_epi32` where different element-size versions of the same operation have to exist, and there is not `_si512` version.

**But there are no merge-masking or zero-masking `setzero` intrinsics in the current version of the intrinsics guide.**  So there's no pattern for `setzero_epi32` to be part of.

---

In asm, there is no `vpxor zmm`, only [`vpxord` and `vpxorq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pxor), because essentially all AVX-512 instructions support masking, and that means there has to be an element size.  (Same for moves like `vmovdqa64` / `32`.)

So does `_mm512_setzero_epi32()` imply use of `vpxord`?  No, Intel's intrinsics guide actually documents it as using `vpxorq`, like all other 512-bit zeroing intrinsics (including `_mm512_setzero_ps()` - fun fact; [EVEX `vxorps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xorps) requires the AVX512DQ extension, not supported in KNL Xeon Phi, only in mainstream (Skylake-avx512 and later) CPU).

As for what zeroing instruction compilers actually choose to use, could be either, and it makes no difference.